# Windows 7 is detecting a non-existent 2nd monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

As of a couple of months ago Windows has started detecting a 2nd "generic non PNP monitor" that is supposedly connected to my laptop. I wouldn't mind this but it's causing problems when I actually do try to connect another monitor. I wasn't able to find any info on the matter and was wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem.

I tried uninstalling the ghost monitor from the device manager but windows somehow "detects" it once again after a while.

I have an NVIDIA GeForce Go 6150 graphics card with the updated drivers and using windows 7 ultimate.

Comment: What does win+P do?

Comment: @KronoS Pressing Win+P allows one to use the Windows 7 Multiple monitor dialog to cycle through the different output options (clone, extend, second only, first only).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may well be a hardware issue.

The presence of a "non-PNP" VGA monitor is detected by just sensing electrical load on the RGB/HV outputs, so a faulty driver chip or short-circuited board can cause misdetection.

If this is the case, having the video card replaced will fix the problem.

Comment: Is there is any alternative solution that this. Mine is a laptop and has same issue.

Comment: But make sure to try [@twobob's answer](http://superuser.com/a/912848/316320) first - it **worked flawlessly** for me.

Answer (score 19):

Choose main display.
Ensure it is "1"

Choose "Show Desktop Only on 1" from drop-down. (hit "Apply")

Choose errant display (which is now grey, not blue)
Choose "Remove this Display"

[image: Screenshot with remove this display]

Comment: The problem is that there is no such an option as "Remove this display" in this dropdown for the ghost monitor.

Comment: Remember to hit "Apply" after choosing to "Show Desktop Only on 1". Then the option to "Remove this display" shows up on the list

Comment: I'd been struggling with this for a few hours. Couldn't get the ghost monitor to go away. Would normally have ignored it but once in a while things would open on the ghost.
This solved the issue. I tried everything else but the "show desktop only on one" and then the disconnect device option was there.
THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

In device manager uninstall all the monitors in there and uninstall the video card, reboot the machine. Reinstall drivers if applicable (I didn't have to when I had this problem). I remember what a pain it was when I was having this issue.. it took me a while to figure out it was the second "ghost" monitor. I wonder if it is only affects people running windows 7? I have not seen this on XP.

Comment: i tried that but it just "re-detects" the ghost monitor after a while...

Comment: Damn, sorry that's all I had, it fixed the problem for me. I had like 4 pnp monitors in there too...

Comment: This issue affects all version of windows using that exact control dialog version only